# 2 different mx namespaces?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

When creating a ViewStack component in FDT, the mx namespace URI is  http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml. The application component and spark components have their mx URI set to library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx.

Any reason ViewStack and presumably other components haven't updated to the new URI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have basically answered your own question.

The `ViewStack` component is an `mx` component which does not have a `Spark` equivalent unlike many other components, hence it uses old mx namespace.

There are indeed other components such as `DataGrid` that will also still be using the old mx namespace.

Comment: I think there more to it than that. I believe that the library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx URI does not contain the Metadata and Script components. When specifying the mx namespace as the library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx URI one must create an additional namespace (fx) for these and other components with the http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009 URI. If there is any documentation regarding this, it would be welcome. SEE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940830/whats-the-difference-between-the-mx-fx-s-object-types-in-flex-4